# Using Linq-To-SQL project in a .Net Core 2.0 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm rebuilding a web app with .Net Core 2. The new .Net Core 2 app references the existing middle-layer app that uses LinQ-To-SQL. However, .Net Core gives an "assembly not found" error.

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

What can I do to make the app work other than rewriting the middle-layer project?

Thanks

Comment: Most practical would be ASP.NET Core 2 on top of .NET 4.x